# How to move a header to the extreme top of the page?

Tags: graphics, header-footer, fancyhdr

I have a image as footer:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength\headheight{26pt}
\fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[width=10cm]{myimage}}
```

The image still starts around 2cm under the top of the page, how let I start it on the utter top?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `\headheight` is different than the top margin value.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer If you want to answer, please do.

Comment: @Johannes_B: Answered!

Answer (score 5):

The `top margin` value is not the same as `headheight`, as can be seen from the graphics (from `geometry.pdf` package documentation). There's a small `\headsep` value too, that serves as vertical spacing between the page header content and the real text body.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[headheight=65pt,tmargin=65pt,headsep=5pt,showframe]{geometry}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{ente}}


\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

If some content shall be squeezed right at the top boundary of the page, `tmargin` and `headheight` should be quite identical, the values in the solution above are just arbitrary ones, depending on the real size of the graphics that should be placed there.

In case the potential warning reported by `fancyhdr` about `headheight` values should not be ignored -- the reported values are quite helpful to prevent wrong page headers!

[image]

Comment: Vielen Dank :-)